# Does cloud foundry support deployment of application in Application Server?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

I would like to develop and deploy an application on an application server like JBOSS or glassfish.  What are application servers supported on cloud foundry?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own CF server this should be the default list:

1. java_web
2. spring
3. lift
4. rack
5. rails3
6. node
7. grails
8. wsgi
9. django
10. php
11. standalone
12. play
13. sinatra
14. otp_rebar

Comment: java_web is a Tomcat server

Comment: You can also run a standalone java application and package your own container, see this [blog](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/11/running-standalone-web-applications-on-cloud-foundry/)